# How to get a while loop once a value exceeds a given value

Tags: labview

I want to get my while loop to sound an alarm when the value exceeds 20. To do this I am trying to use a while loop where if the final value exceeds 20 sound an alarm. How do I get my while loop to stop when the random number is >20? Numeric is equal to 2.1 and numeric 2 is equal to 18, this is so it will show values between 18 and 20. My working so far:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Compare whatever it is you want to be checked against a constant of value 20, and wire the output of that to the stop

Comment: Thanks. First time using labview and couldn't find an example like it anywhere.

Comment: @user3008456 - If this helped, perhaps you might accept the answer :-)